# How to invoke React Component function element from a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have the below function which calls show a modal dialog on click of edit button. How do I render the functional component `UpdateModal` from function showModal?

Here is the function:

```
const showModal = (user: IUser) => {
  setShowUpdateModal(true);
  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <UpdateModal
      
        showUpdateModal={showUpdateModal}
        setShowUpdateModal={
          (bool: boolean | ((prevState: boolean) => boolean)) => 
            setShowUpdateModal(bool)
        }
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

UpdateModal:

```
const UpdateModal: FC<updateModalProps> = ({
  setShowUpdateModal,
  showUpdateModal,
  user
}) => {
  console.log("showUpdateModal....", showUpdateModal);
  return (
    <Modal showUpdateModal={showUpdateModal}>
      <Modal.Dialog>
        <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={() => setShowUpdateModal(false)}>
          <Modal.Title className={`${styles.createText}`}>
            Create User Form
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <UpdateUser user={user} setShowUpdateModal={setShowUpdateModal} />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal.Dialog>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default UpdateModal;
```

Comment: You don't. You can't. `UpdateModal` needs to be *returned* from a React component to be rendered. What are you really trying to accomplish here? Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: First you need to import `UpdatModal` component inside the `ShowModal`

Comment: Please share the  `updateModal` component and also your folder structure.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese I would like to know how do I create another React Component for just this again? I would like to avoid creating multiple components. Updated with UpdateModal component.

Comment: I don't think we really need to see this `UpdateModal` component code, but the parent component code showing where `showModal` is called, and clarity on *where* you actually want `UpdateModal` to be rendered.

Comment: I want UpdateModal to be rendered as modal pop up on top of main page while clicking a button in list

Comment: That's great. Can you add that code to your post?

Comment: @catherine can you share your code on [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you can't return JSX from a callback function and expect React to know it needs to render it somewhere.

The `showModal` callback can update the `showUpdateModal` state and the parent component will be rerendered with the updated state value. From here you just render the modal as part of the render return of the parent component.

Update the `showUpdateModal` state to hold a reference to a specific user, or a null value. Pass this to the modal's `user` prop. All the modal closing actions should set the `showUpdateModal` state back to `null` to close the model.

Example:

```
function UserContent() {
  const [showUpdateModal, setShowUpdateModal] = useState<IUser | null>(null);

  const showModal = (user: IUser) => {
    setShowUpdateModal(user);
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Table responsive striped bordered hover variant="light">
          ...
          <Pen
            color="black"
            size={20}
            onClick={() => showModal(user)} // <-- toggles modal open
         />
          ...
        </Table>
      </div>

      <UpdateModal
        user={showUpdateModal} // user or null
        showUpdateModal={!!showUpdateModal} // <-- toggles modal open/close
        setShowUpdateModal={setShowUpdateModal}
      />

      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

```
type updateModalProps = {
  setShowUpdateModal: (user: IUser | null) => void;
  showUpdateModal: IUser | null;
  user: IUser;
};

const UpdateModal: FC<updateModalProps> = ({
  setShowUpdateModal,
  showUpdateModal,
  user
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal showUpdateModal={showUpdateModal}>
      <Modal.Dialog>
        <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={() => setShowUpdateModal(null)}>
          <Modal.Title className={`${styles.createText}`}>
            Create User Form
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <UpdateUser user={user} setShowUpdateModal={setShowUpdateModal} />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal.Dialog>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did this but I am unable to send "user" on click which is available in showModal().

Comment: @catherine Send "user" on which `onClick`? The one in the table rows? Or you need a way to pass a specific `user` to the `UpdateModal` component?

Comment: yes .. on click of one item in row

Comment: @catherine Ok, updated. Please take a look when you can.

Comment: thank you, but again I get the error on type being null or assignment issues with user={showUpdateModal}  // user or null
               showUpdateModal={!!showUpdateModal} // <-- toggles modal open/close in user component and again on setShowUpdateModal in modal code

Comment: @catherine Just seems to be a typescript thing at this point. Think you could create a ***running*** codesandbox demo of your code we could work with live?

Comment: Thank you, but I will not be able to share it in code sandbox. figuring out how to solve type errors as this is TS

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to conditionally render the `UpdateModal` component in the returned value of `UserContent`. Conceptually this is the flow most often seen:

```
const UpdateModal = (...) => {...}

const UserContent = (...) => {
  const [showUpdateModal, setShowUpdateModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {showUpdateModal ? <UpdateModal /> : null}
      ...
      <Pen color="black" size={20} onClick={() => { setShowUpdateModal(true); }} />

    </>

  )
}
```

This code will trigger rerender when clicking `Pen` because state changes. Then, because `showUpdateModal` is `true`, `UpdateModal` will be rendered. However this will require you to reorganize your code significantly.